# set width of linear layout in horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have the following linear layout,and I am setting it as a child to HorizontalScrollView

File menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/menu"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#2f4f4f" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2f4f4f" android:cacheColorHint="#2f4f4f" android:scrollbars="none">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

File : scrollview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#00ffffff" android:padding="0px"
android:layout_margin="0px" android:fadingEdge="none" android:fadingEdgeLength="0px" android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#ffffffff" android:padding="0px" android:layout_margin="0px">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I am trying to set the width of the linear layout programatically but I am getting ClassCastException.(LinearLayout$LayputParams can't be cast to FrameLayout$LayputParams)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
scrollView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrollview_xml, null);
setContentView(scrollView);
View menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_xml, null);
scrollView.addView(menu);
scrollView.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,100));
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. since the [**scrollView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) extends a FrameLayout , you need to set the layoutParams of its children to have the FrameLayout's layoutParams .
2. since it says you have an exception because you set the layoutParams for the wrong layout , use the correct ones :

   scrollView.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new **FrameLayout**.LayoutParams(100,100));
3. in general , if you have any doubt about the type of the layout , use :

   scrollView.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new **ViewGroup**.LayoutParams(100,100));

Comment: 1.I am getting 0th child of scrollView and thats a LinearLayout,2.using FrameLayout.LayoutParams also gives the same error

Comment: i've corrected my answer . didn't understand the xml part since it wasn't relavant to the question .

Comment: Thanks.I have edited the code but now I am getting-  ViewGroup$LayoutParams can't be cast to ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Comment: did you try to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams ? please try it first , and only if it's general enough, use ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Comment: I also changed the menu_xml to have a frame layout there and used FrameLayout.LayoutParams.Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are type casting the layoutParams, when you can directly use them,

```
scrollView.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,100));
```